# Casella Berger Book Example 4.5.8 Sums of Two Uniform

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

This is a book example, but I'm trying to understand it more fully.

So let X $\sim U(0,1)$ and $Z \sim U(0,\frac{1}{10})$. let X,Z be independent uniform distributions.
Consider Y=X+Z where the joint distribution $f_{XY}$ can be derived from the joint distribution of (X,Z).  So I think this is the joint (X,Z) given $f_{XZ}$ = xz, =(1)(10)=10 for X is uniform, and Z is uniform on $[0,\frac{1}{10}]$

My attempt to work this out is given:  Let X=U, Let Y=U+Z
so For $f_{XY}(x,y) = f_{XZ}(u,y-u)=u(y-u) = 10$ because y-u is in Z (?).  so $f_{XY}=10$ ?

The book explains that by examining the marginal $Y|X=x$ you have Y=x+Z which is uniform on (x,x+$\frac{1}{10})$ and results the $f_{XY}=10$.

my question is how can I show $f_{X+Y}$ using convolution?
How I can solve this using convolution is as follows: Let Y=X+Z
$f_{X+Y}=\int_{0}^{1} f_{X}(y-t)f_{Z}(t)dt$
$f_{X+Y}=10 \int_{0}^{1} f_{X}(y-t)dt$
where the latter is uniform under [0,1] and is equal to 1
so $f_{X+Y}=10$ not sure if this is correct but reasonable.

any help showing that f$_{XY}=10$ using a convolution approach would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think it's Casella and Berger, not Burger.

Comment: Do you agree that the pdf $f_X(x)=1$ on $[0,1]$ whereas $f_Z(z)=10$ on $[0,1/10]$ (in order that the area under the "curve is 1)? Then...